Atiyah-Macdonald: Proposition 7.9.
Proposition 7.9 in Atiyah and Macdonald:
Let $k$ be a field, $E$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $E$ is a field then it is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.
I have a question at the beginning of the proof.
Proof. Let $E=k[x_1,…,x_n]$. If $E$ is not algebraic over $k$ then we can renumber the $x_i$ so that $x1,…,xr$ are algebraically independent over $k$, where $r\geq1$, and each of $x_{r+1},…,x_n$ is algebraic over the field $F=k(x_1,…,x_r)$ ...
Why do we know that there are such $x_1,…,x_r$ and $x_{r+1},…,x_n$ satisfying the conditions above? Is it just something obvious that I missed?

Take any maximal algebraically independent subset (over $k$) of $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Say $\{x_1,...,x_r\}$ is such a subset. Then it is easy to check that the elements $x_{r+1},...,x_n$ must be algebraic over $k(x_1,...,x_r)$, otherwise it would contradict the maximality of $\{x_1,...,x_r\}$.

What confuses me is what if the maximal algebraically independent subset (over k) of {x1,...,xn} is {x1,...,xn} itself?

@Zane Here such a case is impossible, because if $x_1,...,x_n$ were algebraically independent then $E=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ would be isomorphic to the polynomial ring in $n$ variables, contradicting the assumption that it is a field. However, I don't think you really need to split into cases. Pretty sure the proof will work the same for the case $r=n$. (at the end, you want to get a contradiction anyway)

I see. Thank you so much!
